# How to use GetExtension in VS 2010

Tags: c++, c

I'm beginner in c/c++ and find [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the file's suffix and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the file's name and **I have to use these methods** but I can't run the examples in these pages

this is my function

```
void Myfunc(char* filename)
{   
    cout<<GetExtension(filename);
}
```

the error is "GetExtension" is undefined

please help me to get my file suffix and name :)

thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here so that we can see what it is doing. (By the way, those functions are for .NET - perhaps you were looking for [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773587%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead?)

Comment: `I'm beginner in c/c++`  As a beginner, please realize that C and C++ are two separate languages.  `I have to use these methods`  Since you're a beginner, why do you "have to use these methods"?  As a beginner, wouldn't you want the best or industry standard way of getting this information?

Comment: i really dont know, I have to use api functions

Comment: Make sure that you include the right header files. For example, the `PathFindExtension()` function is defined in `Shlwapi.h` ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773587%28VS.85%29.aspx)) so you'd need to add `#include <Shlwapi.h>` or `#include "Shlwapi.h"` at the top of your source code file.

Comment: @GoBusto  this (PathFindExtension) has no error but the out put is something like this: 0921325AF

Comment: @user3105142 See my answer.  You need to understand the difference between a Unicode build and an ANSI build, and what functions to use.

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions at in one place - post them separately, or search to see if they've already been answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of getting the extension from a path name.

One way is to use the functions found in `shlwapi.dll`.  The function you're looking for is `PathFindExtensionA`.

The code below assumes you're using Visual Studio:

```
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib")

//...
void Myfunc(char* filename)
{   
    std::cout << PathFindExtensionA(filename);
}

int main()
{
    Myfunc("TestFile.exe");
}
```

The reason why `PathFindExtensionA` is used is due to you using an ANSI (char *) file name.

See the link below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773587%28VS.85%29.aspx

Basically, `PathFindExtension` uses `TCHAR` as the character type.  Depending on the build settings for your Visual Studio project (again, I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio), the build will either be an `MBCS` build or `Unicode` build.  So unless your string type is an array of `TCHAR`, you can't reliably call `PathFindExtension` unless you know what standard character type to use for the call.

If the build is `Unicode`, `PathFindExtension` will use wide character strings, thus the pointer type you want to use is `wchar_t*` and not `char*`.  If the build is `MBCS`, then the pointer type is `char*` and not `wchar_t*`.  Yes, it gets confusing, but that's what it boils down to.

So to ensure that the correct function is used, regardless of the build type, you either call `PathFindExtensionA` for `char*`, or `PathFindExtensionW` for `wchar_t*`.

Nowadays, MBCS builds are getting more and more rare since Windows by default assumes Unicode, so my advice is to assume Unicode and use wide character strings.

The reason for your original error, where you see some hexadecimal number printed instead of the extension, is that `PathFindExtension` returned a `wchar_t*`, and not a `char*`.  Since `std::cout`'s operator `<<` knows nothing about how to handle a `wchar_t*` in terms of string data, its only other option is to output the pointer value (which is the hexadecimal value you're seeing).

Comment: Minor quibble: That should be `void main()` unless you're returning something.

Comment: thank you, I looking for a way since yesterday...

Comment: @GoBusto No GoBusto, it is correct to use `int main()` and an abomination to use `void main()`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I like the way you think! However, I was referring to the fact that the `int main()` function in your example doesn't return anything.

Comment: @GoBusto - The main() function implicitly returns 0 if no return is given.  This is standard ANSI/ISO C++ behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  I read some were that in C  int main() without return is true, but in C++ is wrong

Comment: I edit my question can you please take a look?

Comment: @user3105142 - Stop reading whatever you're reading.  The `int main()` without a return code in C++ is perfectly valid.

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie, could you comment on why `#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib")` is neccessary? This fixed a build error for me: `unresolved token "etern "C" char* __cdecl PathFindExtensionA(char const*)". Good explanation on the rest!

Comment: The #pragma allows linking to the shlwapi.lib library.  Without linking to this library, you will get unresolved external errors.  See the [Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindextensiona) section.